# How can I retrieve an id from one template's controller and use it in another template's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `index.html` with two templates, `product-list` and `product-details`.  Initially, the `index.html` displays the `product-list` template. Whenever a specific product is clicked, I want to hide this template and show the `product-details` template.

However, I've got a slight problem.  Aside from doing a full redirect to the product details template with the product id in the url, I'm not sure how to pass the `id` of the product that is selected.  Is it possible to pass the id from the `product-list` controller to the `product-details` controller (or directive) without doing something like

```
$location.path('details/' + id);
```

As in can I simply hide the product-list template and show the selected product-details template?

Answer (score 0):

If the two templates are in the same html file you can hide your product-list template every time a specific product is clicked by setting a variable on your $scope that indicate if a product was clicked... toggle it in your on-click function on each product and then use ng-if / ng-show / ng-hide  to show the template you want to show..

if you want to use 2 different controllers you can pass data between them using $stateParams